# Can the coordinating conjunction 'yet' follow a subordinating conjunction?

Tags: grammaticality, conjunctions, coordinating-conjunctions

Is it grammatically permissible by the rules of Standard English for the coordinating conjunction ‘yet’ to follow a subordinating conjunction? For example, take the sentence:

> Although it is early, yet still I must rise.

This seems to make sense and be correct to me, but if I substitute another coordinating conjunction, say ‘but’, it no longer seems so:

> Although it is early, but still I must rise.

It seems that the semantics of ‘but’ are what create a problem here, though instead of the grammar, but I can't seem to form any valid subordinating + coordinating sentence except if I use ‘yet’, so I'm not sure.

Comment: I may be at risk of sounding a fool here, but I don't understand why you'd want to use both. The example you provide is awkward and redundant, and would work better with only one conjunction.

Comment: @Chris - Have you got permission from the original poster at [able2know](http://able2know.org/topic/194468-1) to repost here?

Comment: @Matt The Gravatar is identical on the two postings.

Comment: @AndrewLeach — well spotted! I guess there's nothing to worry about then.

Answer (score 5):

This is archaic but poetic. It's an example of an **anapaestic tetrameter** (although it really needs another unstressed syllable right at the start) — four feet of "da da DUM":

> But although it is early, yet still I must rise.

As @crisis said, it's redundant, but redundancy can be employed for particular effect, as here.

Answer (score 1):

I'd argue the problem with the sentence "Although it is early, yet still I must rise" is that "although" and "yet" are redundant. Both imply a contradiction, so only one should be necessary.

Consequently, I'd use either "Although it is early, I must still rise", or "It is early, yet still I must rise".

Answer (score 0):

As a conjunction is a joining unit, it isn't necessary to use more than one for a single purpose. As you mentioned, writing "but" in place of "yet" doesn't sound right. That's because it isn't, and writing "yet" is similarly so.

If there is a sense in which "yet" does fit this context, it is obsolete.

Comment: The _Corpus of Contemporary American English_ has 700 phrases using _yet still_.

Comment: Your logic about not using two conjunctions together sounds plausible, _and yet_ seems to me to be missing something.  It may be redundant, _but when_ used to good effect, can work well.

Comment: Ha ha. Touché, good fellow.

Answer (score 0):

By definition, coordinating conjunctions connect two *independent clauses*; *although it is early* is a dependent clause and therefore not compatible with *yet* in a single sentence.

Instead of coordinating conjunction, you might want to consider conjunctive adverbs like *however*.

Answer (score 0):

Yet and So, like When and As (which are sometimes included in old FANBOY-style lists) are old adverbs, and it can be difficult to decide when they are being used as conjunctions and when as adverbs, and at what point a common group of words ought to be considered a compound word (nevertheless? Therefor? And yet?).  I'll play agnostic in this case.

Comment: So what is the answer to the question?